# Experiencing SQLiteException error syntax error (code 1) when attempting to create Database table

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, database-connection

New user who just recently got into Android Development here! I can't seem to get around a SQLiteException error I keep receiving when trying to create a table in Android Studio. Its a syntax error but I'm unable to tell where the syntax error on the line is, despite checking similar posts on syntax Errors/SQLiteExceptions. I've included a snippet of code from my LoginDataBaseAdapater.java class below:

public class LoginDataBaseAdapter {

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "regDetailsDatabase.db";
private static final String TABLE_REG_DETAILS = "Registration Details";

public static final int COLUMN_ID = 1;
public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL_ADDRESS = "email_address";
public static final String COLUMN_USER_NAME = "user_name";
public static final String COLUMN_PASSWORD = "password";
public static final String COLUMN_DATE_OF_BIRTH = "dob";
public static final String COLUMN_MOBILE_NUMBER = "mobile_number";


static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_REG_DETAILS + " ("+ COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + COLUMN_EMAIL_ADDRESS + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_USER_NAME + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_PASSWORD + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_DATE_OF_BIRTH + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_MOBILE_NUMBER + " TEXT " + ")";
```

The error message I keep getting is listed below:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.gdick.databasepractice2, PID: 8071      
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gdick.databasepractice2/com.example.gdick.databasepractice2.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Details": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Registration Details(1 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,email_address TEXT,user_name TEXT,password TEXT,dob TEXT,mobile_number TEXT)
```

The syntax error appears to be close to the TABLE_REG_DETAILS part of the create table statement, but I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening. Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this SQLiteException? Many Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private static final String TABLE_REG_DETAILS = "registration_details";
```

and

```
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
```

name of colum can't be a number

Comment: This has fixed it, thanks a million, that was seriously bugging me :)

Comment: @gerard_d You should start considering to accept the answers which solve your problems.